# BIRT possible XSS in XLS format

Tags: xss, birt

I'm trying to fix an issue that exists in XLS and CSV formats and currently it's not handled by the respective BIRT emitters.
For example, using the following section in a rptdesign file, would produce an Excel file(or a CSV file to import in Excel) which opens the calculator application:

```
<cell id="22">
                    <label id="23">
                        <text-property name="text">=cmd|' /C calc'!A0</text-property>
                    </label>
                </cell>
```

Does BIRT support a global handler to parse the BIRT model before rendering and escape such values appropriately?

Or is there perhaps another way to properly handle this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is not a BIRT issue, but an Excel issue. You would have to check and escape the text yourself.

Comment: Besides, my version of Excel (Excel 2007) issues a warning that it is going to start an external application.

Comment: indeed, but if BIRT would put a ' in front of such values, the value is still displayed correctly in Excel and only when editing it the ' would be visible.Also, the warning wouldn't be there anymore.